# alembic autogenerate produces all tables, when head revision already contains them

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

If I do these series of commands in Alembic the result doesn't make sense to me.   I would expect that the autogenerated migration would be empty as I changed nothing in the database between invocations.

Is my understanding incorrect?  I assumed that this would produce an empty change set called "nothing changed"

```
alembic downgrade base   # reset to nothing
alembic upgrade b2   #my revision, this works fine.
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "nothing changed"

INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table '...  For every table
```

Comment: same problem, Did u resolve it?